# Fatal Error in creating new database in Tryton

Tags: python, tryton

I currently installed Tryton in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for GNU Health, a free health and hospital information system. Right now I am trying to create a new database but when I do I get an error message that says:

> FATAL:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "PHT"

I've searched for a solution and and found these:

- https://bugs.tryton.org/issue3220
- [How to get system timezone setting and pass it to pytz.timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218506/how-to-get-system-timezone-setting-and-pass-it-to-pytz-timezone)

I tried editing the config.py file of Tryton with the solutions proposed in those links but still I get the same error.

Here is the current value of timezone parameter in trytond.conf:

```
# Timezone of the server
# timezone = Asia/Manila
```

Comment: What is the TimeZone setting in your conf file?

Comment: @RedBaron - I edited my post and added my timezone setting in my conf file

Comment: Which GNU Health and tryton version are you running?

Comment: @pokoli - I have GNU Health 2.4.1 and Tryton 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you using UTC as timezone, as in the next versions of tryton is the default timezone used.

Answer (score -1):

That entry looks like it's commented (#). Check [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=GNU_Health/Installation#Setting_Up_your_Server_Timezone).