# How do I get the current time and date of the operating system

Tags: python

How do I get the current time and date of the operating system (the one in the clock). I tried to use datetime.now(). But it returns different value.

As suggested by mcalex I've rechecked the time and date setting and this has always been like this:
[image]

Comment: 7 hours difference, and I use UTC+7 timezone, linux ubuntu.

Comment: need to sync hardware & system time.  See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime

Comment: @mcalex it has always been synchronized

Comment: @William: Are you sure? Do you have `UTC=yes` or `UTC=no` in `/etc/default/rcS`? What does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata` command show?

Answer (score 0):

Use `time.localtime()`.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime

> Like gmtime() but converts to local time. If secs is not provided or
>   None, the current time as returned by time() is used. The dst flag is
>   set to 1 when DST applies to the given time.

Comment: Try asking Python for the current UTC time and the current timezone (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218506/how-to-get-system-timezone-setting-and-pass-it-to-pytz-timezone#comment25200533_13218990). One of them should be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python `time` module for various time-related functions.  It appears you are requesting the following format:

*Day Month Hour:Min:Sec Year*

If so, you can use the following:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.asctime(time.localtime())
'Mon Jun 30 22:19:34 2014'
```

To convert to a specific format, you can use the following function:

```
time.strftime(format[, t])
```

This converts a `struct_time` object `tm` representing a time as returned by `gmtime()` or `localtime()` to a string.  See the following link for more info on the format codes:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime

Source: Beazley, D. M., "Python Essential Reference", 4th. Ed.

Comment: Did you sync your hardware and system time as recommended by mcalex?

Comment: In the link i gave, under Multiple Boot Systems Time Conflicts try the suggestion for Make Linux use 'Local' time, ie change the 'UTC=' line in /etc/default/rcS