# Python dt.replace(tzinfo=) doesn't change timezome

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

Why doesn't replace modify the tzinfo object when it recieves a valid timezone
object?

I'm attempting to add the local time to timestamps that didn't specify a
timezone.

```
if raw_datetime.tzinfo is None:
    print(raw_datetime)
    print(raw_datetime.tzinfo)
    raw_datetime.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzlocal())
    print(raw_datetime.tzinfo, dateutil.tz.tzutc())
```

According to the documentation I should be able to change the tzinfo attribute
with a valid datetime

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace

But I'm obviously doing something wrong because the tzinfo object is still
`None`.

```
2000-04-25 12:57:00
None
None tzutc()
```

Comment: Try `raw_datetime = raw_datetime.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzlocal())`. I think datetimes are immutable.

Comment: Total the right answer. I'm a dumb.

Comment: unrelated: `dt  = dt.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzlocal()))` fails if the local timezone had different utc offset at `dt` time, [use `aware_dt = tzlocal.get_localzone().localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None) ` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17365806/4279).

Comment: DO NOT USE datetime.replace(tzinfo= 
 ) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759041/replace-tzinfo-and-print-with-localtime-amends-six-minutes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a simple oversight, replace doesn't modify the calling object but instead returns a new object with the value replaced.

[datetime.replace:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace)

> ***Return*** a date with the same value, except for those parameters given new values by whichever keyword arguments are specified. For example, if d == date(2002, 12, 31), then d.replace(day=26) == date(2002, 12, 26).

Comment: datetime.replace(tzinfo= ) only works for UTC timezone, and fails in many other cases. Do not use.