# Replace "tzinfo" and print with localtime amends six minutes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-datetime, django-timezone

I am creating a DataTimeField no time zone. Soon I am editing this TZ "manually" and then asking to read the value with local TZ. See the end result amends six minutes!

**Logic:**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> test = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 10, 10)
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 10, 10)

>>> test = teste.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' LMT-1 day, 20:54:00 STD>)

>>> timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
>>> timezone.localtime(test)
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 16, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' BRT-1 day, 21:00:00 STD>)
```

NOTE: The idea is that this happens in two stages. First I want to keep on the bench with the TimeZone creation. Then I want to show to the user with the user's TimeZone. In this case both users was the same region.

sorry my English

---

Following the response from @user6897474 and putting in practice, I got this solution:

I'm getting a datetime for POST and serializabel file before saving, do the following:

```
class CheckControllerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        datetime = validated_data['datetime'].replace(tzinfo=None)
        validated_data['datetime'] = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo').localize(datetime)

        return super(CheckControllerSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Replace tzinfo = None, I guarantee you will not have problems with the following error:

> Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use timezone.localize instead of datetime.replace

```
>>> test = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 10, 10)
>>> test = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo').localize(test)
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' BRT-1 day, 21:00:00 STD>)

>>> timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
>>> timezone.localtime(test)
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 28, 10, 10, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Sao_Paulo' BRT-1 day, 21:00:00 STD>)
```

Reference :

1. [pytz.localize vs datetime.replace](https://tilify.com/ying/pytzlocalize-vs-datetimereplace/)
2. [datetime object, when rendered to Django template, was always 6 minutes off](https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/d94a326f8d169105fc39)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Just one last question: Setting the timezone is something global or restricted the request? (I hope it is the second option)

Comment: It should be stateless i.e. second.

Comment: @Francis The link is dead. If possible, it would be better to summarize the content of the linked pages and reference them if they provide further details.