# In flask how to get current time in GMT?

Tags: python, flask

I want to get current time in GMT, like `2015-08-21 05:13:13+00:00` Here you can see that correction is made like 00:00 for GMT, In django they are using `from django.utils import timezone` and `date_to = timezone.now()` to calculate the current time. How I will get the same functionality in flask, Formate of time should be like `2015-08-21 05:13:13+00:00` not like `2015-03-30 07:19:06.746037+02`. I got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344289/python-strftime-a-utc-timestamp-to-local-time-format) but they are using `2015-03-30 07:19:06+02`. I don't want. Just GTM time

Following code is in Django, I want same in Flask, Here they are using `from django.utils import timezone`. In Flask what is equivalent of it, which gives current time in this format `2015-08-21 05:13:13+00:00`

```
import datetime
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone
def calc_date_args(date_from, date_to, date_options):


        try:
            date_to = timezone.now()
            print 'calc_date_args, date_to', date_to   #calc_date_args, date_to 2015-08-21 05:13:13.615541+00:00

            date_from = date_to - datetime.timedelta(days=float(date_options))

        except Exception:
            raise ValueError(_("The time delta must be a number representing "
                               "the time span in days"))

    return date_from, date_to
```

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if you mean UTC time instead of GMT, as most machines consume UTC and most timestamps are in UTC.

In Python 3 to get UTC timezone-aware timestamp:

```
import datetime

def now():
    """Get timezone-aware UTC timestamp."""
    return datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried your method but getting error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timezone'
`

Comment: Your Python version is too old. `datetime.timezone` is available on Python 3.3+