# Equivalent of GNU coreutils /bin/date output with Python2 (timezone)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I want to have a datetime formatted like `%F %T %Z` in Python2.  If I do it naively with `datetime.now()` the timezone part appears empty.  I've learned that Python2 doesn't have support for `tzinfo` objects, but there's a 3rd-party `pytz` module.

Unfortunately, in order to construct a `tzinfo` with `pytz` I still need to name the timezone explicitly.  What I would like to have is a combination of `localtime()` and a *default* `tzinfo`, so that I get current time in local timezone.

Compare the following three outputs:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%F %T %Z")
"2016-01-11 16:13:22 "

>>> import pytz
>>> datetime.now(pytz.timezone('CET')).strftime("%F %T %Z")
"2016-01-11 16:13:37 CET"

>>> from time import localtime
>>> datetime(*(localtime()[:7])).strftime("%F %T %Z")
"2016-01-11 16:14:24 "
```

The second one is what I want, sans the need to specify the timezone explicitly.  On the other hand, `/bin/date` doesn't need any hint to look the timezone up:

```
$ /bin/date
Mo 11. Jan 16:17:31 CET 2016
```

Looking at the source code for `date(1)` I can see that when compiled with glibc it relies on `tm_zone` field being part of `struct tm`, but otherwise will require `TZ` environment variable to be set.

Any ideas how to make this work with Python2 w/o hard-coding the timezone?

Comment: Your OS knows the timezone, but not necessarily in a form that `pytz` can understand. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218506/how-to-get-system-timezone-setting-and-pass-it-to-pytz-timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a platform with `/bin/date` (non-Windows), to print the current local time in a given format:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%F %T %Z')
'2016-01-12 08:12:50 CET'
```

To reproduce it portably, you need `tzlocal` that finds `pytz` tzinfo that corresponds to your local timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal  # pip install tzlocal

local_time = datetime.now(tzlocal.get_localzone())
print(local_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z (%Z)'))
# -> 2016-01-12 08:12:51+0100 (CET)
```

[`%F`, `%T`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) are not portable.

This code works even during a DST transition when the local time may be ambiguous.