# How to handle POSIX timezone information (like CST) for pytz?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz, timestamp-with-timezone

I have timezone string `'CST'` and try to use it within `pytz`.

Unfortunately this fails:

```
cst = pytz.timezone('CST')

File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 181, in timezone
  raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'CST'
```

What do I have to do to avoid this error?

Comment: related: [How to get system timezone setting and pass it to pytz.timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13218506/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CST` unto itself is not a valid time zone identifier.

There is no way to know whether `CST` is to be interpreted as (US) "Central Standard Time" (UTC-6), "Cuba Standard Time" (UTC-5), or "China Standard Time" (UTC+8).

Instead, pass a fully qualified locality-based [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `America/Chicago`, `America/Havana`, or `Asia/Shanghai`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz


def valid_timezone(timezone):
    try:
        pytz.timezone(timezone)
    except pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError:
        return False
    return True

if valid_timezone('CST'):
    # go ahead...
    pass
else:
    # not supported timezone..
    pass
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.