# 1 hour off when converting RFC 2822 date to datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, utc

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate
>>> tup = parsedate("Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:15:00 GMT")
>>> tup
(2016, 1, 22, 10, 15, 0, 0, 1, -1)
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> timestamp = time.mktime(tup)
>>> timestamp
1453454100.0
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 22, 9, 15)
```

I'm using the `email.utils.parsedate` function to parse an RFC 2822 date to a struct_time. This looks correct, the hour part is `10`. Then, I convert it to a timestamp using `time.mktime`,  and then, I try to get a UTC datetime out of it using `datetime.utcfromtimestamp`, but for some odd reason, the hour in the datetime is `9`. I don't really get why.

I'm in UTC+1, so there's probably a conversion to local time happening somewhere, but I have no clue where.

Comment: What's your time zone?

Comment: I'm in UTC+1. Using parsedate_tz doesn't work either. It returns a timezone offset as an extra element in the tuple, but doesn't impact the rest of the tuple. So there's probably a conversion to local time happening somewhere, but I have no clue where.

Comment: Maybe the `email.parsedate` function treats `GMT` as a time zone, and includes Daylight saving time? In general I would avoid mixing several different modules like you do here (email, time and datetime). `pytz` is a very good package for dealing with time and timezones.

Comment: The problem is that time.mktime expects the time tuple to be in local time. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447632/python-convert-utc-time-tuple-to-utc-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mktime` expects the tuple to be in local time. There's also `calendar.gmtime`, which expects it to be in UTC. I might actually just end up using dateutil as @Boaz recommends

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just to use `dateutil`
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil

It converts it directly to a correct datetime object

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:15:00 GMT")
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Time access and conversions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html):

> time.mktime(t):
>   This is the inverse function of localtime(). Its argument is the struct_time or full 9-tuple (since the dst flag is needed; use -1 as the dst flag if it is unknown) which expresses the time in local time, not UTC.

For correct results you should use `calendar.timegm()`:

```
>>> calendar.timegm(tup)
1453457700
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use datetime.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> d = "Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:15:00 GMT"
>>> dt.strptime(d, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 22, 10, 15)
```