# Django - Editing the settings Default Time Zone

Tags: python, django, python-datetime, django-timezone

I'm now going through the process of making a django application time zone aware. Initially, the `TIME_ZONE` setting was set to "America/Los_Angeles", but I've decided that it's probably more standard to make it "UTC".

I discovered some unintended behavior when I render a `datetime` to a web page in Javascript like so (`start_date` is a naive `datetime` that I define earlier in the view):

django view: `cal_start_date = time.mktime(start_date.timetuple())`

js: `startDate = new Date(response.cal_start_date * 1000)`

Depending on the `TIME_ZONE` I set in settings.py, I get a different timestamp for `cal_start_date` which is understandable: the `time.mktime` method returns a floating point number representing the number of seconds since the epoch (01/01/1970). However, the number of seconds since the epoch depends on the time zone we are referring to. I believe that `time.mktime` is automatically taking the `TIME_ZONE` setting as the one to use for this reference, right?

In general, is it bad practice to change the django `TIME_ZONE` setting?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956886/python-calendar-timegm-vs-time-mktime):

> [time.mktime()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) assumes that the passed tuple is in local time,
>   [calendar.timegm()](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) assumes it's in GMT/UTC. Depending on the
>   interpretation the tuple represents a different time, so the functions
>   return different values (seconds since the epoch are UTC based).
>
> The difference between the values should be equal to the time zone
>   offset of your local time zone.

I also recomend you ensure that `USE_TZ = True` in your settings.py