# Django model datetime - weird unix timestamp

Tags: django, timezone

I store a datetime in database (SQLite). I save python `datetime` objects with UTC timezone (so they are aware) in my models. When I check the database I literally see `2018-02-28 00:00:00`.
When I fetch data from database I see:

```
>>> Price.objects.last().datetime.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=59, tm_isdst=0)
```

So far so good (time is really a midnight). But once I try to divide UNIX timestamp I get wrong result:

```
>>> time.mktime(Price.objects.last().datetime.timetuple()) / 3600 / 24
17589.958333333332
```

When I adjust the timestamp with +1 hour it's finally right.

```
>>> (time.mktime(Price.objects.last().datetime.timetuple()) + 3600) / 3600 / 24
17590.0
```

What do I do wrong? Why `struct_time` shows hours=0 and minutes=0 but once I call `time.mktime` it gets wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function mktime take time in local time, so I assume your computer is in a UTC+1 timezone (without considering summer time, which is considered by mktime).

See [Python - calendar.timegm() vs. time.mktime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956886/python-calendar-timegm-vs-time-mktime) on how to "make time" with UTC (GMT) times.

Answer (score 0):

When you save your model, do you use django `timezone` class ?

`from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()`

and put in `settings.py` :

`USE_TZ=True`

Source here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

I think your problem is what you put in your model.

Comment: As I wrote my data are 100% ok in database. The issue is when I calc unix timestamp.